# How to remove the last character from all lines but only if it is a certain character

Tags: linux, string, sed

i have data in this form

```
Kure|Hiroshima
Kure|Hiroshima
Kure|Hiroshima
NO MATCHING
Aachen|
Darmstadt
Mulheim
Aachen|
```

and i want to remove the last character only if it is a pipe (|).

desired output

```
Kure|Hiroshima
Kure|Hiroshima
Kure|Hiroshima
NO MATCHING
Aachen
Darmstadt
Mulheim
Aachen
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` for this:

```
$ sed 's/|$//' file
Kure|Hiroshima
Kure|Hiroshima
Kure|Hiroshima
NO MATCHING
Aachen
Darmstadt
Mulheim
Aachen
```

It looks for `|` together with `$` (which means "end of line") and deletes it.

Note you can use `sed -i` in case you want to do an in-place edit.

Comment: Ooh that was quick and it works perfectly!! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version:

```
awk '{sub(/\|$/,"")}1' file
```